# SVD: Matrix size mismatch: Part 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, transpose

I'm reading [this article](https://jonathan-hui.medium.com/machine-learning-singular-value-decomposition-svd-principal-component-analysis-pca-1d45e885e491).

In the "Proof" section, there is an equation:

$A^T = (USV^T)^T = VS^TU^T = VSU^T$

I don't understand the $VS^TU^T = VSU^T$ part.
Is this $VSU^T$ simply a typo?

If we borrow the following matrix A from the "Example" section:
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 & 2\\\ 2 & 3 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
, the shape of S would be 2 x 3:
$$
S=
\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & 3 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So, $VS^TU^T$ works because (3 x 3)@(3 x 2)@(2 x 2),
while $VSU^T$ doesn't work because (3 x 3)@(2 x 3)@(2 x 2).

Am I correct, or missing something?

Comment: It isn't a typo. It is a genuine mistake.

Comment: @user1551 Could you elaborate on that? How could you prove it? To make matters worse, this result is used in the next equation: $A^TA = VSU^T(USV^T) = VS^2V^T$. Now I'm completely confused about this entire proof section ...

Comment: @user1551 Ah, it makes sense! $A^TA = VS^TU^T(USV^T) = VS^2V^T$! In the Part 2 of this question, I've been asking how a non-square matrix can be squared. Of course, it's impossible because this is **a genuine mistake**. Could you make it an answer, so that I can accept it? Anyway, +1. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a typo. It is a genuine mistake. $A^TA$ is equal to $VS^TSV^T$, not $VS^2V^T$. Since $S$ in general is not a square matrix, it cannot be squared in the first place.

In fact, not only is the equality $A^TA=VS^2V^T$ wrong, the author's attempt to prove the existence of SVD is also wrong.

In essence, the author tries to prove that if $A=USV^T$, then each column of $V$ is *necessarily* an eigenvector of $A^TA$ and each column of $U$ is *necessarily* an eigenvector of $AA^T$. However, he hasn't justifed why $U$ and $V$ exist. That is, he hasn't justified why we can always find an *orthonormal* set of eigenvectors of $A^TA$ or $AA^T$.

But there is an even bigger issue. The author tries to solve for $V$ and $U$ separately without considering the consistency between the two solutions. However, given an orthogonal matrix $V$ whose columns are eigenvectors of $A^TA$ and given an orthogonal matrix $U$ whose columns are eigenvectors of $AA^T$, it is **not** necessarily true that $S=U^TAV$ is a diagonal matrix with a nonnegative diagonal. For example, pick any orthogonal matrix $A\ne I$. Then $A^TA=AA^T=I$. If we take $U=V=S=I$, then $A^TAV=S^TSV$ and $AA^TU=SS^TU$. Yet, $A\ne I=USV^T$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I accepted your answer. I calculated what you wrote (Please beat me if I'm wrong): I picked an orthogonal matrix $A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \pmatrix{1 & -1\\1 & 1} \neq I$. Then $A^TA = AA^T = I$. If we take $U = V = S = I$, then $A^TAV = IV = I^TIV = S^TSV$ and $AA^TU = IU = II^TU = SS^TU$. Yet, $A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \pmatrix{1 & -1\\1 & 1} \neq I = USV^T (= III^T)$. Simply, $A \neq USV^T$. This contradicts to the assumption $A = USV^T$.

Comment: @IanHacker $A=USV^T$ isn't an assumption, but something that one needs to prove. It's OK to assume that a SVD exists first and solve for $S,U$ and $V$, but one must verify that the solution one obtains is indeed valid. In the author's case, And the author of the article fails to do that.